# How to generate apk on server with changing application name and icon automatically in Android?

Tags: android, windows, magento, server, apk

I want to link my Magento store with the android application and i want to make android application for my magento store.

For that I have referred following link to make the android application using magento store.

http://www.appypie.com/android-app-builder

https://www.simicart.com/

https://www.appsgeyser.com/

Might they setup Android studio in server? if yes then how to change that files automatically and then run the script for generating the apk file.

What's the process behind for above link? I want to make similar like this.

I want to change application name and logo automatically which is entered by user so it can generate the application and provide it to user from his/her magento store.

If any have idea about this type of logic or how to do that then it will be helpful to me.I will be thankful to all of them.